# Updating rows with 388 columns in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with updating a table inside a MySQL database with about 388 columns. Inserting new rows works great, but updating existing ones doesn't (**I do not get any error messages**). I am also not very sure if the way I use to insert/udpate the 
data is the very best as I do have a very long code, which is also very fragile for errors. Well, I am sure this could be solved a lot better!

Here is my code: https://codeshare.io/5DZODE

What if I use this code for every single of those 388 values?

```
insert into $table (field, value) values (:name, :value) on duplicate key update value=:value2
```

Help and ideas for improvement would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Its too difficult to see you code... can you make it short and share....be reducing columns

Comment: That would be no problem, but maybe those deleted lines were those with the problem inside?

Comment: Table with 388 columns is not well designed. You should keep your code simply and clear which cannot be done with so big table.

It would be better if you split that table into few smaller. I can see that there are also duplicates of many columns. After some modifications you would end with 3-5 tables with 5-10 columns each. Don't search bug in that code but redesign it. It seems that you want to keep everything in one row in one table. Let's say you have blog - would you make table with columns like "comment1, comment2, comment3, ... comment100" and add 100 more columns after 100th comment?

Comment: Ah, ok. So how many columns would you suggest max? I have 388 values to store :) 5 tables with 10 columns would be not enough.

Comment: Database normalisation (in this case refactoring) is not easily explained in some absolute numbers. I agree de-duplicating columns will make your code more readable, maybe boost performance (when you can properly set foreign keys or at least indexes). If you do not want to and only fix this issue. I would suggest looking at the query limit lengths in MySQL and PHP. Most likely cullprit is that the query is 'to long'. Or maybe the MySQL library has a limit. I would look at your code, but that links seams to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "REPLACE INTO" Statement instead of insert, that way you will only have to print the data once
eg

```
REPLACE INTO `values` (`id`,...) VALUES ($id,...)
```

Also to improve the php code(to make it more fail proof) I Would probably make an array containing all the variables and then print the SQL statement based on those values FX

```
$values = array('id'=> $id, ....);
$columns = array();
$replaceValues = array();
$insertValues = array();
foreach ($values as $key => $value)
{
     $columns[] = "`$key`";
     $replaceValues[] = ":$key";
     $insertValues[":$key"] = $value;
}
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xyz;dbname=xyz','xyz','xyz');
$statement = $pdo->prepare('REPLACE INTO `values` ('.implode(',',$columns).') VALUES ('.implode(',',$replaceValues).')');
$statement->execute($insertValues);
```

Comment: How so? it still uses the PDOs insert mechanism, and the keys are defined by the code, not a request. Also I fixed an error in the code after you wrote this, when defining the $values array

Comment: If that's the fact, i'll try this one here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: come on, you *don't* define an array with 388 columns in the code. Really do you?

Comment: No problem, also please note I spotted another error when defining $values array, instead of an array containing arrays it should of course be an associative array with values. @Your Common Sense, I usually don't, but that does not mean it is prone to SQL injection

Comment: On a side note, $insertValues is superfluous, as $values could serve as well

Comment: If you don't, it means your code is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: So you argue, that by typing in 388 columns manually in the array, it makes the code prone to Injection? I can see how that might be the case, if you add $value => $value2 in the $values array instead of 'key' => $value , but I wouldn't call the "prone to SQL injection".

Comment: by typing in 388 columns manually in the array, it makes the code safe. However, you DON'T type them in => it's prone to injection. Sounds logical?

Comment: Yeah sure if you instead of typing them in accept user input instead of the entire array. But I made the code specifically typing them in as array('id' => $id ...), if you change the code to contain a userdefined array it is not the same piece of code. As the author of this question also typed alot of columns and variables in his code, I assumed he'd want to do the same kind of thing

Comment: So, in the end splitting in several tables would be the better solution?

Comment: @user1898027 what about REPLACE INTO? What if I need to insert, not only update values?

Comment: Yeah it probably would be better to split the data somehow for the sake of easier dealing with it. Depending on your usages you could also have a "json_encoded"/(otherwise serialized) object in a datacolumn, where the bulk of the columns could reside(if you don't need to query those specific columns).  Replace INTO tries to insert, but if an entry with the primary key exists, it deletes the existing row before inserting

Comment: Cool! I guess I am a friend of `Replace INTO`.